# How best to use both Xcode and Visual Studio with the same git repo?

Tags: c++, xcode, git, visual-studio-2012

Apologies for a newbie question. I'm setting up a code repository and project(s) for my company; ultimately I'll be bringing on more experienced programmers than I - but I want to do sensible things from the ground up.

I've been working on a c++ library project in Visual Studio, with a git repository. VS is a nice development environment but I'd also like to work on my mac (and deploy for the mac).

I like the fact that my VS Project is all set up with different configurations for debug builds etc etc - it really makes compilation etc very easy. Git of course is now supported by VS so I can manage my repo from within the same interface. I'd like to be able to do the same on my mac with an Xcode Project.

Questions:

1. Is this sensible?
2. Is it done routinely, or is there a better way of achieving what I'm after?
3. Assuming 1. and 2. don't establish me as a loony, how do I do it?

   - specifically, in Xcode I can't 'create a new project under source control' without creating an entirely new git repository. I need to create a new project, under source control - but using an existing git repo. Can someone help with the steps to set this up please?

I'd be grateful for any comments on the subject of multiple projects on the same source, or of course more specific answers.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is indeed very sensible to use the same source control for both types of projects.
2. Yes, I'm sure it is. I'm using git both at work and for my hobby projects at home.

I'm pretty sure that both MS and Apple tools are also able to interact with an existing git repository. You may well have to manually build the project in the respective tools - but this is simply because "Create new project" is really not meant for when you already have a bunch of source-files in the first place.

For a larger project with many different parts, you will probably also want to have several project files that use the same source files, so you will need to somehow manage these things in a way that doesn't involve just clicking a few places. But once you have built your project definition files for the respective IDE, it should be perfectly fine to store all your source and project definitions in a git repo.

And yes, you want a single repo for all (or as much as you can of the) related source - otherwise you will need to keep track of, for example, which version of your project X goes with which version of test Y (because ultimately, you will update X to work differently, so test Y will need to be changed simultaneously - much easier to do that if you have one version control repo than if you have, say, your testcode in one repo and the production code for project X in another repo  - it is generally hard enough to do these things with a single repo!).